# evaluating limit of two functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $P(n) = a^{P(n-1)}-1$  such that for all $n = 2 ,3 ,$ and so on.   And let $P(1) = a^x -1$   where a belongs to all real positive numbers, then we have to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to0} P(n)/ x$     where $x$ apoaches to zero .

I tried it and found that there is indeterminancy of $0/0$

But I cannot go further as I cannot apply series and l hospital.

Comment: I think you typed something wrong. P(n) is constant we respect to $x$ so that limit diverges to infinity.

Comment: P(1) is like another function

Comment: It is but it's not a function of x.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows why it is not a function of x

Comment: Because you wrote it as a function of n.  If you want it as a function of x then the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: P(1) and P(n) are different . P(1) is unique among P(n).

Comment: Oh.  I misread.  Anyways this doesn't work because $P(x)$ isn't continuous on some disk around 0.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows but p(n) is divided by x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = a^x  - 1$, your $P(n)$ is really a function in $x$ obtained by composition of $f$ with itself for $n$ times. $$P(n) = f^{\circ n}(x) \stackrel{def}{=} \underbrace{f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{n \text{ times}}(x)$$
Since $f$ is a differentiable function in $x$ and $f(0) = 0$, you have $f^{\circ n}(0) = 0$ and

$$\ell_n \stackrel{def}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{P(n)}{x} = 
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f^{\circ n}(x)}{x}
= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f^{\circ n}(x) - f^{\circ n}(0)}{x-0}
= \left.\frac{d}{dx} f^{\circ n}(x)\right|_{x=0}
$$
Apply chain rule to $f^{\circ k}(x)$ for a generic positive integer $k$, we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[ f^{\circ k} (x) \right] = f'(f^{\circ k-1}(x))\frac{d}{dx}\left[ f^{\circ k-1}(x)\right]$$
At $x = 0$, this give us $\ell_k = f'(0)\ell_{k-1}$. From this, we can deduce
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{P(n)}{x} = \ell_n = f'(0)\ell_{n-1} = f'(0)^2 \ell_{n-2} = \cdots = f'(0)^n = (\log a)^n$$

Comment: How you have differentiated it

Comment: @kabira Aside from the notation you use, your $P(n)$ is a function in $x$, in fact a differentiable one. Since above derivation only uses the definition of differentiation and chain rule and doesn't involve L'Hospital rule nor any series, I didn't see any issue in differentiate them.

Comment: After differentiating , how we get the result

Comment: Because of the recurrence relation between $\ell_k$ and $\ell_{k-1}$, you only need to compute one deriviative $f'(0) = \left.\frac{d}{dx}(a^x - 1)\right|_{x=0} = \left.\frac{d}{dx}(e^{(\log a)x} - 1)\right|_{x=0} = \left.\log a e^{(\log a)x}\right|_{x=0} = \log a$.